# Hyperlink in gridview and then want redirect to another page for registration, if person get registered the hyperlink text get change

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have tried with grid-view and link-button but its not working.It shows me the correct changes in link-button text but not redirect to another page.
In grid view one link column present. when i click on link it should redirect to another page say registration page and fetch data of that particular row. when i registered, the link in grid-view of that row will change to another text say 'Thanks for register'. How i implement this, should i use grid-view and hyperlink or anything else. I am stuck in this please help me.

Comment: You should demonstrate your current code, with any attempts to implement this issue yourself.

Answer (score 0):

use a link button in grid view and in the click event redirect the page to the desired page attaching the query string.
Then in the page load event of requested page fetch the data using the query string.

code is as follows

...

' runat="server">delete

aspx.cs file
protected void gridview1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
           response.redirect("desiredpage.aspx?id=your command argument")
}

on page load of desired page
assign the value of request.querystring("id") to a variable and then use it to display data of that particular record

use a literal in designing and on the click event of submit button
write the following code
literal.text="thanks for registration";
literal.visible=true;